# How can I validate multiple form with one request file in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have three form and I want to validate them within one request file.How to check the form identity within the rules method.I'm confused.I wrote this but It didn't work.here is my code

```
 //rules method
    public function rules()
 {

   switch ($this->check())
    {
        case 'personal':
            return ['fanme'=>'required'];
            break;

        case 'career':
            return ['career'=>'required'];
            break;  

        case 'summary':
            return ['summary_info'=>'required'];
            break; 

        default:
             return [];
            break;
   }
}


//my own method
public function check()
 {
  return $this->input('form_identity');
 }
//form field
<input type="hidden" value="personal" 
 class="form-control required" 
 name="form_identity"/>
```

Comment: Can you show the acctual forms? do you submit them with one submit button?

Comment: NO but my route is same i want to insert value also in switch case in controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention exactly why your existing code doesn't work, but you have the right idea.  Keep it simple though:

```php
public function rules() {
    switch ($this->form_identity) {
        case 'personal':
            $rules = ['fanme'=>'required'];
            break;
        case 'career':
            $rules = ['career'=>'required'];
            break;
        case 'summary':
            $rules = ['summary_info'=>'required'];
            break;
        default:
            $rules = [];
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

You have access to the full `Request` in your Form Requests (`$this`), so you can test on anything available in the request - eg input values, method (`POST`, `PATCH`, etc), authenticated status, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use form inputs with unique identifier added to each form

```
public function rules()
{
    $data = request()->all();
    $serviceName = isset($data['serviceName'])?$data['serviceName']:'';

   // IF it is API CALL, you can use header
   // $serviceName = request()->header('serviceName');

    switch ($serviceName) {
        case 'userRegister':
            $rules = [ 
                'serviceName' => 'required',
                'firstname' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/u|max:36',
                'lastname' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/u|max:36',
                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'
            ];
            break;
        case 'codeVerify':
            $rules = ['activation_code'=>'required'];
            break;
        case 'summary':
            $rules = ['summary_info'=>'required'];
            break;
        default:
            $rules = ['serviceName' => 'required',];
    }
    return $rules;
}
```